# javascriptのwindow.open()で別窓がうまく開けない

Tags: javascript

環境: winodws10、IE11（IE設定のタブ：ポップアップ設定：IEで自動判定）

javascriptの`window.open()`の第三パラメータに

```
toolbar=yes,location=yes,status=yes,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes
```

上記のオプションをすべてをyesで設定するとなぜかタブで開かれてしまいます。
いずれか一つをnoに設定すると新規ウインドウで開かれるのですがすべてyesでうまく新規ウインドウで開かれない原因がおわかりの方がいましたらよろしくお願いいたします。

またchrome、edgeでも同様の現象となりました

Comment: 全てデフォルト値だからではないでしょうか？第3パラメータは未指定だと新規タブで開きますので、デフォルト値から変更がないと未指定と同じ扱いになってしまうのでは？

Answer (score 1):

Windowのサイズ(Width,Height)を指定したら新しいウィンドウで開くと聞いたことがあります。

追記：
簡単に書いたコードなので、かなり行儀が悪いですが、以下のような感じで小窓が開きます。

```
<html>
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="window.open('test.html', 'test', 'width=500px,height=400px')">button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。状況といたしましては、すべてのパラメータを指定して別窓で開きたかったのですが、ご丁寧に感謝いたします。